# Является ли фразеологизмом?

Tags: фразеология

Является ли фразеологизмом - тоска в глазах?

Answer (score 2):

«Тоска в глазах» — это не фразеологизм.

> ФРАЗЕОЛОГИ́ЗМ, -а, м. Лингв. Устойчивое сочетание слов, значение
> которого в целом не выводимо из значений составляющих его слов. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Например:

> Зеленая тоска — о томительной, невыносимой скуке. *— Ну что, весело
> тебе было вчера? Он ответил с угрюмым раздражением: — Тоска зеленая! Я
> лучше удить рыбу буду.* М. Горький, Мать. [Словарь русского языка
> Евгеньевой]

Зная, что такое «зелёная» и что такое «тоска», непонятно, что это буквально значит.

> ТОСКА́, 1. Тяжелое гнетущее чувство, душевная тревога.
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]
>
> ГЛАЗ... мн. глаза́ ... 1. Орган зрения. || Взгляд, взор. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

«Тоска в глазах» — значение выводимо из значений составляющих слов: тяжелое гнетущее чувство во взгляде.

Comment: «Выйти сухим из воды» — «значение» выводимо из слов, потому что фразеологизм — это фигуральный прием, который когда-то был кем-то использован,понят, и в последствии устоялся в речи.

Answer (score -1):

Да, это фразеологизм. Фразеологизм — это сочетание слов, которое является фигуральным приемом, который когда-то укоренился в речи. «Тоска в глазах» — это фигуральный прием, укоренившийся в речи. Данный фразеологизм используют для того, чтобы охарактеризовать человека, который по внешним признакам испытывает тоску.

Comment: Ссылку на словарь можно в ответе дать?

Comment: Нет, нельзя....

Comment: Искры из глаз; в глазах потемнело; по глазам видно; глаз не оторвать; невооружённым глазом (видно); не верить своим глазам; пускать пыль в глаза; для отвода глаз; глаз-алмаз; глаз да глаз нужен; не сводить глаз; не отвести глаз; глаза на мокром месте; глаза слипаются; глазом не успеешь моргнуть... Тут хорошая коллекция: https://burido.ru/razvitie-i-obuchenie/401-frazeologizmy-o-glazakh